# Maximo Web Service Data Filter

Tags: soap, wsdl, maximo

I've created an enterprise web service in maximo that uses extsys1. In extsys1 I've created a duplicate of MXPERSONInterface and managed to create a query from it (sync was default). Now when I finished my web service I can succesfully query maximo from soap ui client and get all the person data but what I'd like to know is, can I select which data I want to export in my response ? Like...ignoring everything except name/lastname/email or anything like that.

If anyone did that / knows how with any other mbo any help would be very much appriciated. The thing is I don't want all the raw data being in my response, want to make it as much user-friendly as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do import/export of data via Web Services that are 
dynamically accessed from external applications.

Another thing to note when you're accessing pre-defined object structures in
this way is that the response will always contain every single field that exists 
in that object structure.

I will write down a brief tutorial on how to filter that data so that when
you query your object structure you only get a partition of the data in the response.

For the sake of this tutorial I will use MXPERSON and will export Firstname, Lastname, City,
Country and Postalcode.

First go to Integration > Object Structures > Create New Object Structure.
Name it `My_MXPERSON`, set to be consumed by `INTEGRATION`, set Authorized application `PERSON` and add new row for Source Objects and select `Person` from object list. Now you can go to More Actions > Include/Exclude Fields. Here you should un-check everything except Firstname, Lastname, City, Country and Postalcode (only them need to be CHECKED). Click save.

Now we need to create an enterprise service by going to Inegration > Enterprise Services > New Enterprise Service. Call your service `My_MXPERSON_ES`, for Operation set `QUERY` and for Object 
Structure select your `My_MXPERSON` you created earlyer. Click save.

Next thing is to create a publish channel by going Integration > Publish Channels > New Publish
Channel. Name it `My_MXPERSON_PC` and for Object Structure select your My_MXPERSON (If you can't find it on the list go to your Object structure and uncheck *"Query Only"* box. Click save.

Now you have everything set up to create your external system. Integration > External Systems > New External System. name it `My_MXPERSON_EXTSYS`, set End Point to which format you want your response
to be in, I use `MXXMLFILE`. On the left side you have 3 typees of queue you need to set up, I have 1 option for first 2 and 2 for last one (select the upper one - ends with cqin). Check Enabled.
Within your External System go to Publish Channels and Select your `My_MXPERSON_PC`, enable it.
Within your External System go to Enterprise Services and Select your `My_MXPERSON_ES`, enable it it. Click save.

Last thing you need to do before you're done is to create your web service, go to Integration >
Web Services > New Web Service from Enterprise Service. Name it `My_MXPERSON_Query`, and select from list My_MXPERSON_EXTSYS_My_MXPERSON_ES, select your Web Service from the list and go to more actions > deploy.

Once your Web Service is deployed you can access the wsdl file from *servername/meaweb/wsdl/webservicename.wsdl* .

For test here we will use SoapUI to test the wsdl file.
Create a new Soap project and copy / paste the url of the wsdl file. If it loads succesfully paste this in the xml request field.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:QueryMy_MXPERSON baseLanguage="EN" transLanguage="EN">
         <max:My_MXPERSONQuery>
            <max:PERSON>
               <max:Firstname> Name you want to query </max:Firstname>
            </max:PERSON>
         </max:My_MXPERSONQuery>
      </max:QueryMy_MXPERSON>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Remember to swap "Name you want to query" with the actual name in your table.
Hope this guide helped.

Comment: Nice work! Bruno also has similar steps for creating a flat file for export. The steps are nearly identical except towards the end... Http://maximodev.blogspot.com/2013/04/flat-csv-file-export-maximo-integration-framework.html

Comment: I had to do it with xml-format so it never crossed my mind to look for "flat-file" guides, would save me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

- Using Maximo 7.5.0.5, Go To > Integration > External Systems
- In External Systems, pick your system that you want to filter records for
- Go to the Publish Channels tab
- Click on Data Export
- In the Export Condition field, enter your where clause to filter your record set

[image: Export Condition]

I referenced these steps from IBM Help:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v27r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itam.doc%2Fmigrating%2Ft_asset_disposal_export_data.html

Normally, I just reference the link. In my experience though, IBM's web site frequently changes URL structure and occasionally goes offline for "maintenance". For accessibility, I am including the text here. No offense to copyright.

**Exporting asset disposal data**

To provide information for review or for a company that you hire to dispose of assets, you can use the integration framework applications to export a data file with information about assets that you are planning to dispose of.

**Before you begin**

Before you attempt to export a file, check that the following tasks are completed:

- JMS queues are configured. You can use either continuous queue or sequential queue, depending on your business process.
- The external system for asset disposal integration is enabled.
- The publish channel is enabled.

**About this task**

The following procedure explains how to export asset disposal data.

**Procedure**

1) On the navigation bar, click **Go To > Integration > External Systems**.

2) On the List tab, select the TAMITEXTSYS external system.

3) On the Publish Channels tab of the External Systems application, select the ITASSETDISPOSAL publish channel and click **Data Export**.

4) In the **Export Condition** field in the Data Export window, enter an SQL statement that is appropriate for the Maximo® database that you use. This statement specifies the export condition.

Typically conditions filter by location, by site ID, and by status, as shown in the following example.

`location = 'DISPOSAL' and siteid = 'BEDFORD' and status not in ('DECOMMISSIONED','DISPOSED')`

The SQL statement must use the database names for attributes as shown in the field help. To view the field help, position the cursor in a field and press Alt+F1. The field help displays the database table and column (attribute) in the following format: ASSET.SITEID, where SITEID is the attribute name.

5) Click OK to export the asset data.

**What to do next**

The location to which the file is exported depends on the global directory set for the system and on the filedir parameter for the endpoint of the external system. If no global directory is set, look in the root of the application server folder. If no filedir parameter is set for the external system, look in the 'flatfiles' sub-directory. For example,

`C:\bea\user_projects\domains\maximo_database\flatfiles\TAMITEXTSYS_ITASSETDISPOSALInterface_1236264695765361846.dat`

Another way to locate the file is to search the operating system file structure for TAMITEXTSYS_ITASSETDISPOSALInterface*.dat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will vote up since it really IS the answer on how to export data from maximo but as I said in my question I need a wsdl (soap) version that can be done automaticly from another external app. Managed to find the answer for it anyway but thanks for the reply once again.

Comment: I see you want export condition to be flexible. I see my answer is not the answer. I'm curious to know what the steps are for the soap client. Could you post the answer on here for the benefit of others?

Comment: I've answered if you want a general pic / or any1 else but will updatei it with the whole lot of details once our network is back up and I'm able to access maximo.

Comment: you can also import the wsdl file into Web Service Consumer and make a connection with your code, used to do it with regular IBM Web Services and it worked great with LS / JS, should also work with this web service.